# Testing R library load functionality with shell script

Tags: r, bash, shell

I have R installed in my Linux system. I also have a package "x" installed. I want to write a simple shell script to check if that library is getting loaded properly or not. Also let say there is a API available named as 'f' in that 'x' package my shell script should be able to run it and verify if it worked without any error.

In short I want to test below R functionality with a help of a shell script. IF below thing works return true else false

```
$ R 


Copyright (C)  The R Foundation for Statistical Computing
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)

R is free software and comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY.
You are welcome to redistribute it under certain conditions.
Type 'license()' or 'licence()' for distribution details.

R is a collaborative project with many contributors.
Type 'contributors()' for more information and
'citation()' on how to cite R or R packages in publications.

Type 'demo()' for some demos, 'help()' for on-line help, or
'help.start()' for an HTML browser interface to help.
Type 'q()' to quit R.

R > library(x)
 library loaded
R> f(c(1,2,3))
 #No error thrown
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should work like this:

```
R --no-save <<EOF
library(x)
f(c(1,2,3))
EOF
if test $? = 0 ; then
  echo "good"
else
  echo "bad"
fi
```